# Why is it Showing List index Out Of Range Error?

Tags: python, list, count

I am trying to count occurences of only positive integer elements in a test list using only a single list instead of a dictionary to reduce space complexity. 
But the below code fails, unfortunately. Can anyone explain why?

```
def count_items_from_list2(List):
    count =[0]*max(List)
    '''
    from collections import defaultdict
    count = defaultdict(lambda:0) 
    '''
    distinct_element_count=0
    for i in range(len(List)):
        if count[List[i]]==0:
            distinct_element_count+=1
        count[List[i]]+=1
    return [(List[i],count[List[i]]) for i in range(len(List))],distinct_element_count

List = [5,4,8,2,4,9,22,50,79,22,50,50,66,33,8,4]

items_count,distinct_elements = count_items_from_list2(List)

print("Count of all items: ",items_count)
print("No of distinct elements: ",distinct_elements)
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full traceback.

Comment: You are trying to reduce space complexity, but if your `List` is `[2, 57]` you will create another list of size 57 for no good reason... Conclusion: use a `dict`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
count =[0]*max(List)
```

**With:**

```
count =[0]*(max(List) + 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add 1 here:

```
count = [0] * (max(List) + 1)
```

Indexing starts with 0 and in your code when you access by index 79, it fails because the last one is 78.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t give count the right size:

```
def count_items_from_list2(List):
    count =[0] * (max(List) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

List = [5,4,8,2,4,9,22,50,79,22,50,50,66,33,8,4]

print(Counter(List).keys()) # equals to list(set(List ))
print(Counter(List).values()) # counts the element's frequency
```

Output:

```
dict_keys([5, 4, 8, 2, 9, 22, 50, 79, 66, 33])
dict_values([1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1])
```

> Why is it Showing List index Out Of Range Error?

You can try to print the index passed to your list `count`.

The issue is with your line `count = [0] * max(List)`.

You need to scale your `count` list by `max(List) + 1`. Indexing in Python (and many other programming languages) starts with 0. I tried to run your code and it fails when it tries to access 79th index in your `count` list. 79 happens to be the max int in your list `List` and it's corresponding index should be `79`. However, since the size of your `count` list was 79, it's last index would be 78 (as index starts from 0).

```
count = [0] * (max(List) + 1)
```

I am assuming you have only `positive integers`. If you `List` won't have 0 int, then you can also do this:

```
if count[List[i] - 1] == 0:
   distinct_element_count += 1
count[List[i] - 1] += 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.The information was regarding counter was very helpful but the time complexity in high in list(set(list)) or collections.counter rather than this approach of list or dictionary.I tried to minimise both time and space complexity here.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to upvote and accept my answer!